# Android multiline EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

I've one EditText with multi-lines.

The problem is that, while I am adding more and more lines, just pressing ENTER or typing, the `EditText` keeps scrolling down which is OK, but after approx. 10 lines whole activity is scrolling.

And when I click again on `EditText`, the opened keyboard covers whole `EditText`.

But, when I click only on 3rd line, keyboard isn't covering `EditText` and `View` is moved like it should have.

Any advice please?

Comment: Your question is not very clear... Please add some screenshots and code.

Comment: Do you use a `ScrollView` for your layout?

Comment: hello, scroll view is above of edittext... edit text is not in scroll view

Comment: here you can find screenshot: http://postimg.org/image/4dti153yj/ the left image is scrolling edittext, but when i reach X lines and press enter or start new line whol activiy scrolls like on right picture

Answer (score 1):

Okay,Using **`EditText in ScrollView`** Like this way

```
 <ScrollView 
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#54D66A"
        android:textSize="17sp" />

</ScrollView>
```

For programmatic approach please check

> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/method/ScrollingMovementMethod.html

Answer (score 0):

You can give `android:maxHeight="60dp"` to your `EditText` to stop scrolling of the whole Activity and it will solve other problem also.

I hope it helps.